# Modifying Unity Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I am trying to modify a unity game by changing lines in `managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll` but it doesn't seem to work.
However when I make changes in `managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll` I get the desired outcome. I am using dnSpy to make changes to the files.

Can someone explain why I don't see any changes in the game when modifying `managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll`? Maybe rephrased, what files from this list can I change with dnSpy and why can't I change all?:

```
managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll
managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll
```

PS: Maybe I didn't have a good understanding about methods I was changing in `managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll` and thats why I didn't saw any changes in the game.

Comment: Not entirely sure what **Assembly-UnityScript.dll** for one thing, I can't locate it in my installs.  Where did you find it?  My only guess it is for the defunct _Unity Script_ JavaScript-like programming language.   If so that would explain why nothing happens.

Comment: _"...what files from this list can I **change**..."_ - as  this involves de-compilation and/or modification of Unity binaries you would need to refer to Unity's T&Cs as such question's are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be concerned with what is or isn't allowed whilst de-compiling or modifying pay-ware binaries.

Comment: @MickyD no, my question is not of legal nature, I am asking why I can't see any results when modifying some files which contain game logic. If you made that assumption because I upvoted your comment, sorry, I just watned to say that I agree, for questions about what is allowed and what not I should read the T&C.

Comment: @MickyD all files I listed are in the following location: ```managed``` folder which is in the installation folder of the game

Comment: _"I am using dnSpy to **make changes** to the files...what files from this list **can I change** with dnSpy....no, my question is not of legal nature"_ - don't forget your `reverse-engineering` & `decompiler` tags.- Just because you want to go from A to B doesn't mean there isn't a speed camera along the way.

Comment: @MickyD "can I change" is meant like how and when does Unity load all the different dll and how are they used and what they contain, the question is not about whether its legal or not.  For example, in ```managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll``` there is a class which gives a random color to a specific ingame item, I tried to change that class so that it gives always the same color to that Item by replacing the random rgb components with fixed, it didn't work, but when I made changes to the ```managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll``` so that enemies are immortal, it did work. I hope you understand.

Comment: @MickyD I did think about the legal status of my actions, and I know my thinking is not the law, but I am sure I am allowed to alter the logic of a single player unity game(my private copy at home). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246854/discussion-between-mickyd-and-a-a).